# Pelican complains about SITEURL even though it has been set

Tags: pelican

I have specified SITEURL in the configuration.

But yet, if I import a blogger site, pelican will warn about it not being set?

```
(pelican) root@localhost:~/website# grep SITEURL pelicanconf.py 
SITEURL = 'http://stolk.org/blog'
(pelican) root@localhost:~/website# pelican-import --blogger ~/blog-11-24-2021.xml  
[20:11:52] WARNING  Feeds generated without SITEURL set properly may not be valid                                       log.py:91
           WARNING  No timezone information specified in the settings. Assuming your timezone is UTC for feed           log.py:91
                    generation. Check https://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/settings.html#TIMEZONE for more information          
content/bugs-in-complex-software.rst
content/switching.rst
content/bi-colour-led-bars.rst
...
```

Why does pelican think it is not set?

pelicanconf.py:

```
AUTHOR = 'Bram Stolk'
SITENAME = 'stolk.org'
SITEURL = 'http://stolk.org/blog'

PATH = 'content'

TIMEZONE = 'America/Vancouver'

DEFAULT_LANG = 'en'

# Feed generation is usually not desired when developing
FEED_ALL_ATOM = None
CATEGORY_FEED_ATOM = None
TRANSLATION_FEED_ATOM = None
AUTHOR_FEED_ATOM = None
AUTHOR_FEED_RSS = None

# Blogroll
LINKS = (('Pelican', 'https://getpelican.com/'),
         ('Python.org', 'https://www.python.org/'),
         ('Jinja2', 'https://palletsprojects.com/p/jinja/'),
         ('You can modify those links in your config file', '#'),)

# Social widget
SOCIAL = (('You can add links in your config file', '#'),
          ('Another social link', '#'),)

DEFAULT_PAGINATION = False

# Uncomment following line if you want document-relative URLs when developing
#RELATIVE_URLS = True
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the source code of pelican_import.py file and found that it does not read the `pelicanconf.py`.  The source code calls the `read_settings()` function which only reads the `DEFAULT_CONFIG` (defined in settings.py).

The `read_settings` function looks like this,

```
def read_settings(path=None, override=None):
    settings = override or {}

    if path:
        settings = dict(get_settings_from_file(path), **settings)

    if settings:
        settings = handle_deprecated_settings(settings)

     ......
     ......
     return settings
```

You somehow need to hack the `pelican_import.py` to pass a `path` argument (absolute path to the `pelicanconf.py` file) to the function calls. It is called 6 times in the `pelican_import.py`.

The easy way probably is to make a copy of the file `pelican_import.py`, name it `my_pelican_import.py` and manually change those function calls. Then run the Python file on command line like this,

```
$python3 my_pelican_import.py .......
```

Answer (score 1):

uncomment the line `#RELATIVE_URLS = True` when in development